# Define $A=${$x\in\mathbb{R}: \left| 2x-1\right| < 11$}. Find supremum of $A$.

Tags: real-analysis

**Step I**. We need to show that $A$ is bounded from above by $6$. i.e., for all $a\in A$, $a<6$.
   Take $a=\left| 2x-1\right| < 11$ for some $x\in\mathbb{R}$. *(WHY ''for some'', why not ''for all''?)*. Hence, we obtain $-5 < a < 6$. Hence, for all $a\in\mathbb{R}$ $A$ is bounded from above.

**Step II**. We need to show that if $y<6$ then $y$ cannot be an upper bound for $A$. So, I couldn't show. Can you hint? And can you explain my question:*(WHY ''for some'', why not ''for all''?)*

Comment: Hint: $x_{\epsilon} = 6-\epsilon/2 \in A$ for every $\epsilon \in (0,1)$.

Comment: I think, we can show to use without epsilon.

Answer (score 1):

Since $x \in \Bbb R$ you could choose $x=100$. In this case $a=|200-1|=199$. So we have found a value for x within its domain ($x \in \Bbb R$) and for which $a \geq 11$. Thus it does not hold for all x.

As for the hint of question two: notice that a has to be strictly less than 11. The idea of real space is that between any two numbers there are infinitly many other numbers. So if $y<6$, could you find another number $p$ such that $y<p<6$?

Comment: I couldn't find.

Comment: You should use the hint by Hello, you are required to use some general concept like the epsilon.

Comment: So take any number $-5<y<6$. Note that there exists a positive number $\epsilon > 0$ such that 6 could be written as $6=y+\epsilon$. Knowing this, is there something you can think of that would be larger than $y$, but smaller than 6? If so, you have proven that $y$ cannot be your upper bound.